# CakePHP3/DebugKit translation cache taking ridiculos time to read/write

Tags: cakephp, caching, cakephp-3.0

Just started baking a new project with Cake 3 and got an issue. 
I baked MVC for users, and have a very simple view, the users index, that is taking something like 10seconds+ to load. Debug kit shows this:

```
Core Processing (Derived from $_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME"]) 28,10   
Cache.read translations.debug_kit.it_IT    11.727,79    
Event: Controller.initialize    36,53   
  Cache.read default_users  0,82    
  Cache.write default_users 1,81    
Event: Controller.startup   3,86    
  Cache.read translations.cake.it_IT    0,85
[...]
```

So the cache read for translations takes a lot of time (it's not only debugkit's but also the cake's core sometimes). Disabling debugkit solves the problem.

Had the same problem before changing locale from en_US to it_IT.

The /tmp folder is writable, so it is /tmp/persistent (chmod 777 for debugging).

The cache engine in use is the default, File, but I also tried using Memcached.
I also tried switching the database configuration for debug_kit, from sqlite to mysql, but nothing changed.

Any advices? Thanks!

Comment: Does that happen in a virtual machine or in your production server?

Comment: On my development vagrant box

Comment: Also tried to change the cache engine to Memcached, but the problem still remains. In this case DebugKit doesn't show strage time for the single request, but the overall time is still over 10 seconds.

Comment: Do you host your project files in the host machine or in the vagrant box?

Comment: The web server is on the vagrant box, so are the project files, which are synced via NFS with the host machine.

Comment: I could only guess that it is because of disk or network latency, but it is also possible that  you have a php version having an unserialize bug that makes stuff slower

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77215/discussion-between-mfrascati-and-jose-lorenzo).